# UK Visitor visa from India. Cooling off period

Tags: uk, india, standard-visitor-visas, repeat-visits

I am asking this question after reading through most of the related/relevant question-answers and I believe my query is not a duplicate. Please highlight otherwise and my apologies if it is so.

My in-laws are in the UK now on a visitor visa that expires on 1 Nov 2017. They are having to leave the UK soon to attend a family emergency back in India (death of a close relative- follow up rituals take 13-15 days) and they want to be with the relative's family for an extended period in India. For this reason, I am planning to bring them back by Feb-Mar, by applying for another visitor visa. I am assuming this will be risk-free as I've heard of a certain unwritten rule of a 6 month cooling off period.

Now, my query is- is the 6-month cooling off period from the day the visitor visa expires?- in which case they can only apply for a visitor visa with a tentative travel date on or after 2 May 2018

(or)

Is the 6-month cooling off period from the time they leave UK? in which case they can apply for a visitor visa for a travel date that is 6 months from the date they leave UK, tentatively (if they leave mid-June 2017) early Jan 2018.

Thanks
VK

Comment: There is no such thing as a cooling off period between visitor visas; it's an internet myth

Comment: Thank you @Gayot Fow. How do I/applicant convince UKBA that I/Applicant will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home?

Comment: See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab